# Can someone identify the font for English text in this love plus logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can someone identify the font for English text in this love plus logo. I've tried sites likefont.com and myfonts.com but have have no luck. It would be very much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: If the question is about the English letters only, why not cut off the upper line?

Comment: because it might be possible to identify the font based on the japanese characters

Comment: Please see https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions

Answer (score -1):

This is the closest font i can find. it is called "Rounded Blocks"

https://fontineed.com/font/30186_rounded_blocks